# How to render UserControl with parameters in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I use following code to render `UserControl`.

```
//render control to string
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(b));
this.LoadControl("~/path_to_control.ascx").RenderControl(h);
string controlAsString = b.ToString();
```

But I want to pass to `UserControl` some **parameters** so it should get data and update its properties ***just before rendering.***

How it could be done? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376310/load-user-control-dynamically-with-parameters):

> Just load the control using the path of the .ascx file, cast to proper type and set the properties one by one:

```
MyControl myControl = (MyControl )Page.LoadControl("~/path_to_control.ascx");
myControl.Param1= 1;
myControl.Param2= 2;
myControl.RenderControl(h)
```

OR:

```
Page.LoadControl(typeof(MyControl), new object[] {1, 2}).RenderControl(h);
```